# jQuery Resizable handles setter not working

Tags: jquery, setter, resizable, handles

i'm using jQuery UI Resizable, and i need to set handles option after the initialization.

I followed the [API example](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) and initialization method works just fine, but setter method seems not working.
Am i missing anything?

```
// Initialization works fine!
$('#containerGreen').resizable( { handles: "n, e, s, w" } );

// Setter NOT working
$('#containerRed').resizable();
$('#containerRed').resizable( "option", "handles", "n, e, s, w" );
```

Live [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7aFLr)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug:

> http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3423

Workaround from the issue:

> 

A dirty solution is to enable all the handlers that you are going to need on init.

Add a class like the following in CSS

.ui-hide-handler {
    width:0 !important;
    height:0 !important;
}

and add/remove the class to the handler DIVs according to your needs

$('.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se', element).addClass('ui-hide-handler');
$('.ui-resizable-sw', element).addClass('ui-hide-handler');

As I said, it's dirty solution but it works.