# Change dynamically jQuery resizable handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handler, resizable

I'm trying to change the handler on a resizable element but it don't seems to works.

I used :

```
$(line)
    .draggable({containment:"parent"})
        .resizable({
            containment:"parent",
            handles: "e, w"
        });
```

and now I want to pass the handler from "e, w" to "n, s", but when I do :

```
$(line)
.resizable({
    containment:"parent",
    handles: "n, s"
});
```

My handlers don't change. Why ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option setter for this option is currently missing: [bug link](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3423) but once it gets resolved you can call the resizable `setOption` method for the `handles` option:

```
$(line).resizable("option", "handles", "n, s");
```

Meanwhile do the following:

```
var options = {
    containment:"parent",
    handles: "e, w"
};
$(line)
.draggable({containment:"parent"})
    .resizable(options);
```

Then when changing the handles do:

```
options.handles = "n, s";
$(line).resizable("destroy");
$(line).resizable(options);
```

Comment: I'm happy you can read that piece of code, OP's line breaks really confuse me `乁(@﹏@)ㄏ`

Comment: @MaximeOzenne This is called after the resizble is already initialized. http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Comment: Ok I think I have something wrong with my code... Thanks anyway i'll try to make it works

Comment: Update the question will all of the code so I can look at it :)

Comment: This is a big project, normally it's a dynamic div added by a button which took the resizable function, I think it will a bit confusing

Comment: It's seems to be a known bug :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513019/jquery-resizable-handles-setter-not-working

Comment: I see, the setOption is missing. What I will suggest is to modify the object you instantiate with and to call destroy on the widget and instantiate it again. I will update the answer.